# How to write a tester for a program that writes one bit at a time?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a tester for the following program to see if it functions correctly, however, I'm not sure if I implemented flush() correctly and for some reason I don't get any output. Can someone suggest code that will test this class to see if I implemented flush and writeBit correctly?

```
#ifndef BITOUTPUTSTREAM_HPP
#define BITOUTPUTSTREAM_HPP
#include <iostream>

class BitOutputStream {

private: 
  char buf;             // one byte buffer of bits
  int nbits;            // how many bits have been written to buf
  std::ostream& out;    // reference to the output stream to use

public:
  /* Initialize a BitOutputStream that will 
   * use the given ostream for output. 
   * */
  BitOutputStream(std::ostream& os) : out(os) {
    buf = nbits = 0;    // clear buffer and bit counter
  }

  /* Send the buffer to the output, and clear it */
  void flush() {
  out.put(buf);
  // EDIT: removed flush(); to stop the infinite recursion
  buf = nbits = 0;
  }


  /* Write the least sig bit of arg into buffer */
  int writeBit(int i) {
  // If bit buffer is full, flush it.
  if (nbits == 8) 
    flush();

// Write the least significant bit of i into 
// the buffer at the current index.
// buf = buf << 1;  this is another option I was considering
// buf |= 1 & i;    but decided to go with the one below

  int lb = i & 1;      // extract the lowest bit
  buf |= lb << nbits;  // shift it nbits and put in in buf

  // increment index
  nbits++;

  return nbits;
  }
};

#endif // BITOUTPUTSTREAM_HPP
```

What I wrote as a tester is:

```
#include "BitOutputStream.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  BitOutputStream bos(std::cout);  // channel output to stdout
  bos.writeBit(1);
  // Edit: added lines below
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(0);
  bos.writeBit(1);

  // now prints an 'A' ;)

  return 0;
}
```

I know this is wrong since I get no output and have no way to see if the implementation is correct.  I appreciate any input you can provide.

I compiled the code with:
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp BioOutputStream.hpp BitInputStream.cpp
and ran it with:
./a.out

Comment: Your test function never actually calls `BitOutputStream::flush()`.

Comment: How can I fix that? I tried BitOutputStream::flush() but still got no output.

Comment: Add a call to `bos.flush();` after your call to `writeBit()`.

Comment: Oh and I just noticed that your `flush()` method calls itself - this will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually I'll make this an answer.

Comment: ok I got a seg fault after adding bos.flush() after writeBit()

Comment: segfault perhaps due to....  wait a minute, what site is this?  Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're never actually calling `BitOutputStream::flush()` - add a call to `bos.flush();` following your calls to `writeBit()`.
2. Your `flush()` method is recursive - it calls itself, which will result in an infinite loop. Remove the call to `flush()` within the definition of `flush()`.
3. Your test as is probably won't print anything because a single bit will equate to ASCII value 1, which isn't printable. Try adding a few more bits. E.g. `writeBit(1); writeBit(0); writeBit(0); writeBit(0); writeBit(0); writeBit(0); writeBit(1);` should print an A.

Comment: Still seg faulting, even after doing the steps above.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save before rerunning, no seg fault now but still no output.

Comment: sorry brother, I was adding too many 0's when I did exactly like you specified above, I indeed printed an 'A' thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

Put your conditional call to `flush()` at the end of `writeBit()`, and not at the beginning. Then you will have an automatic flush after the 8th bit, and not waiting until you write the 9th bit.

To test your code, I would read bytes from stdin, feed them bitwise to writeBit, and check if the inputfile and outputfile matches.

Comment: when I use input file and output file I get different results. For example if my input file is just 'A' and I read it in and do bos.writeBit(ifile.get()); seven times I get '}' here is the hex dump for input 0a41 and for output 007d. What could account for the correct output when I don't use input/output files and incorrect when I do?